# Can $a^{x}$ be never an integer for fixed real number $x$ and any integer $a$?

Tags: number-theory, analysis, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, real-numbers

A very simple question popped up while solving another problem:

Is it true that for any fixed real number $x$, the equation

$$
    a^{x} = b
$$
has integer solutions $a,b>1$?
It is easy to prove that if $x$ is rational, the answer is YES, but what about other real numbers?

Comment: Since there are only countably many pairs of integers $(a,b)$ there can be only countably many $x$ that work here.

Comment: Well, $x = \log_a b$ will have integer solutions.  There will be solutions for *some* irrational values of $x$ but by lulu's comment not all and only countably many.  If $a^x = b$ then $x= \log_a b$ any number and only numbers of the form $\log_a b$ will have solutions.  (And for any $q = \frac mn$ then $q=\log_{2^n} (2^m)$ is in that form.)

Answer (score 4):

Note that, if we have such an equation,  $x$ is determined uniquely by $a,b$, indeed $x=\frac {\ln b}{\ln a}$.

As there are only countably many pairs of integers there can only be countably many such $x$.  Hence there must be uncountably many real $x$ for which there is no such equation.

Answer (score 4):

If $a$ is an integer, not equal to $0$ or $1$, and $x$ is a non-rational algebraic number, $a^x$ is a transcendental number by the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GelfondsTheorem.html), hence there are no solutions for $a^x=b$, for $b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Actually, this is a particular case of this theorem, and the same conclusion holds if $a$ is an algebraic number $\neq 0,1$.